# Pass different models to Web API

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have this method in my ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("get")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetKeysValues(GetKeysModel model){
     ...
}
```

And GetKeysModel is:

```
public class GetKeysModel
    {
        public PaginationOptions pagination { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public int PageId { get; set; }
        public List<int> Languages { get; set; }
        public int KeyType { get; set; }
        public int KeyValueStatus { get; set; }
        public string KeyName { get; set; }
    }

 public class PaginationOptions
    {
        public int Page { get; set; }
        public int NumPerPage { get; set; }
        public string Order { get; set; }
    }
```

So when i send this json format from Fiddler all parameters is passed as well:

```
{
Pagination:{Page:1,
NumPerPage:20,
Order:"Key.Id"},

ProjectId :2,
PageId :1,
Languages: [1,2],
KeyType: 0,
KeyValueStatus:0
}
```

But in another model structure, by deriving:

```
public class GetKeysModel : PaginationOptions 
        {
            public int ProjectId { get; set; }
            public int PageId { get; set; }
            public List<int> Languages { get; set; }
            public int KeyType { get; set; }
            public int KeyValueStatus { get; set; }
            public string KeyName { get; set; }
        }
```

I try to send this json:

```
{
    Page:1,
    NumPerPage:20,
    Order:"Key.Id",
    ProjectId :2,
    PageId :1,
    Languages: [1,2],
    KeyType: 0,
    KeyValueStatus:0
}
```

And my nodel is `NULL`. What need to be a Json format for this scenario?

Comment: The JSON format is right. How does your actuion look like? The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Hi JotaBe. Thanks for reply. There is no error, just my model is null: http://screencast.com/t/T4Lhdir1Fg7

Comment: _Technically_ that's not valid JSON. The properties should be wrapped in `"`. e.g. `{ "Page":1,"NumPerPage":20,...}`

Comment: @BradChristie Ok, *technically*, but in the context of Web API, JSON.NET serializer, and this question, it's a perfect JSON document ;)    To avoid other people being mislead.

Comment: @OlegYudovich But I wanted to see your Action signature :( Not an inexistent error.

Comment: Brad Christie - you are right, but valid json not fix the problem

Comment: JotaBe - my action is request from Fiddler: http://screencast.com/t/n5kSkVKpZ

Comment: Every time I've had a null model like this, it's always been some obscure serializer settings. Take the JSON as a string and try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetKeysModel>(json) and see if it works. Check your web api config and see if there is any custom settings being added.